# UWP: How to specify pane border when the pane is close?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Just a quick question, I am using SplitView and I tried to create a left border when the pane is closed. (Note: I placed the pane on the right).

Is it possible? I've tried:

```
<SplitView DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False" OpenPaneLength="320" PanePlacement="Right">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <Border BorderBrush="black" BorderThickness="1 0 0 0">
            ...
            ...
            ...
        </Border>
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

But the border only appear when I open the pane.

Sorry for this silly question, but UWP is new to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using the default style of the control.
By default, the pane `visibility` is set to `collapsed` when the `IsPaneOpen` property is set to `false`

If you want to do so, you will have to create your own style for the splitview.

Here is the default style (visual state manager has been removed)

```
<Style TargetType="SplitView">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="OpenPaneLength" Value="{ThemeResource SplitViewOpenPaneThemeLength}"/>
    <Setter Property="CompactPaneLength" Value="{ThemeResource SplitViewCompactPaneThemeLength}"/>
    <Setter Property="PaneBackground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="SplitView">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">


                    <!-- Content Area -->
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <Border Child="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="LightDismissLayer" Fill="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <!-- Pane Content Area-->
                    <Grid
                        x:Name="PaneRoot"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding PaneBackground}"
                        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.OpenPaneLength}">
                        <Grid.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry x:Name="PaneClipRectangle">
                                <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="PaneClipRectangleTransform"/>
                                </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                            </RectangleGeometry>
                        </Grid.Clip>
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform x:Name="PaneTransform"/>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <Border Child="{TemplateBinding Pane}"/>
                        <Rectangle
                            x:Name="HCPaneBorder"
                            x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}"
                            Width="1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```